# One SelectFeature control for every Layer?

Tags: openlayers-2, features

I would like to have one SelectFeature control for every layer so that I can have different representational behaviour for every layer.
Means in one layer I want to highlight the features when the mouse hovers in the next not.

When I do this, only the most upper layer is producing onSelect-Events!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This](http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html) is the example using same SelectFeature control on multiple layers. Unfortunately the configuration on the control should be consistent, for example, if you define the control as `hover: true`, then features on all layers can be selected by mouse hover. In other words, you cannot do something like hover selection in layer A while click selection in layer B by using a single SelectFeature control. There might be a way to do this job, but I guess it's non-trivial.

Comment: thx, I got mad trying out all possible configurations without any success!

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to define individual select control for each layer. Then you can use radio buttons to activate control on selected layer and deactivate in others.Eg

```
selector1 = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(building,{
        onSelect: onFeatureSelect,
        onUnselect: onFeatureUnselect
    });
map.addControl(selector1);

selector2 = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(facility,{
        onSelect: onFacilitySelect,
        onUnselect: onFacilityUnselect
        //hover:true
    });
map.addControl(selector2);
```

then use radio button to activate and deactivate controls

```
<input type='radio' id='radFacility' value='Facility Wise' checked='checked' onClick='selector1.deactivate();selector2.activate();' name='toggle' defaultChecked='yes'/><label for='radFacility'>Facility</label>
<input type='radio' id='radBuilding' value='Building Wise' onClick='selector2.deactivate();selector1.activate();' name='toggle'/><label for='radBuilding'>Building</label>
```

Comment: This is a good idea but I needed it simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the events property on layer. eg.

```
Layer1.events.on({"featureselected":function1()});
```

For hover you will have to use the control, i don't know other way.